# How to check whether the fields of \maketitle command is empty

Tags: macros, luatex, expl3, variable

As some people know,i insert tags for command \maketitle and it fields ()@author,@date,\thanks and \title). All works ok,but for @thanks it show,that variable is empty,but it is not empty. I tryed to use tl_if_empty ctf|ntf|Ntf,but it fix this issue,but show not empty @author and @thanks,even if i haven't it in my document. Help me please,how i can correct check,whether this variable empty. For example if i haven't author,variable @author should be empty. Thanks everybody for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true,tagunmarked=false,log/all}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop
  {
    @author = H1 ,
    @date   = H1 ,
    @thanks = H1 ,
    @title  = H1 ,
  }
  \makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[1]{\footnotemark
    \protected@xdef\orig@@thanks{\orig@@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#1}}}
\makeatother
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kozlovskiy_maketitle:
  {
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc { orig@##1 } { ##1 }
\tl_if_empty:cTF{##1}
{
\use:c { orig@##1 }
}
{
\cs_gset_protected:cpn { ##1 } {
\tagstructbegin{tag=##2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=##2}
\use:c { orig@##1 } 
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
}
\__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle:
    \tagstructend
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle: \maketitle
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \maketitle { \kozlovskiy_maketitle: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\author{alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
\title{test document%
  \thanks{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
  }
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\maketitle
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
Test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\thanks` doesn't store its contents like `\author`, `\date` and `\title` do. Instead, it appears in the arguments to those commands and then produces the footnote when the title is output. The default behavior is to populate the macro `\@thanks` with a series of `\footnotemark` commands, *but* this does not happen *until* the title is typeset, so you won't see anything in the command until the values set by `\author` etc. are expanded. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I suspect part of your difficulty lies in not wanting to dig into the code of `\maketitle` which is not only where `\@thanks` gets populated, but also where `\@thanks` gets cleared.

Comment: So to solve this problem,i should check @\thanks command inside \@title command,or save in some variable value of parameter of \thanks command?